# How do you do an ElasticBeanstalk deploy for multiple docker containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm doing an eb deploy like so:
(This is one line, I broke it up for readability)

```
eb create --platform "multi-container-docker-1.7.1-\(generic\)" 
my-web-and-api --profile default --region us-west-2 --cname 
mycname --tags STACK=mystack
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment.
```

My Dockerrun.aws.json looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "my-docker-config",
    "key": "Dockercfg"
  },
  "volumes": [],
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "name": "my-web",
    "image": "my-web:multi",
    "environment": [{
      "name": "Container",
      "value": "Node.js"
    }],
    "essential": true,
    "memory": 128,
    "links": [
      "my-api"
    ],
    "mountPoints": [],
    "portMappings": [{
      "hostPort": "80",
      "containerPort": "5000"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "my-api",
    "image": "my-api:multi",
    "memory": 128,
    "environment": [{
      "name": "Container",
      "value": "Node.js"
    }],
    "essential": true,
    "mountPoints": []
  }]
}
```

I've tried AWSEBDockerrunVersion with the 2 in quotes and without, but I get the  same error no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.  The problem was that I was escaping the parenthesis.  Don't do that and it works.